# Orchard CMS content item's type could not be changed programmatically

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, orchardcms

I created a content item's instance as follows:

```
ContentItem ci = _orchardServices.ContentManager.New("ContentTypeA");
_orchardServices.ContentManager.Create(ci, VersionOptions.Published);
ci.As<SomeContentPart>().SomeAttr = value;
...
_orchardServices.ContentManager.Publish(ci);
```

In another method I need to change it's content type, and I tried the following without success:

```
ci.TypeDefinition = _contentDefinitionManager.GetTypeDefinition("ContentTypeB");
ci.ContentType = "ContentTypeB";
```

When I query the Content Item again, its content type is still "ContentTypeA" instead of "ContentTypeB".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once a content item has been created, you can't change its content type. Well, in theory you could hack into the database and make it work, but it seems like a much better use of your time to just create a new item and copy the data.

Comment: Thanks Bertrand. I am importing Sharepoint Documents into Orchard. So, every time a Sharepoint document's content type is changed I would need to recreate the content item. Looks like a bit untidy for me :S. I know that this feature is not high priority, but would be nice to have it available.